# Can I ask medical questions about the courses I study here?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to this community!

I was wondering if I can ask questions about the doubts I have in the courses I study, I'm 1st year MD student and I'm not sure if my questions are suitable for this community.

The courses I take right now are Anatomy, Physiology, Biochemistry, and Histology.

Comment: In addition to Ian's answer, https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic is the place to see what's officially on-topic. It also mentions other SE sites like Biology may be better for the more fundamental questions that apply to all organisms or all animals, but as long as you relate it to human health and medicine it's fine here, too. One important rule to note is that we discourage posting the same question to multiple sites, so you'll have to choose the best home for each question you ask.

Comment: One additional point to Ian and Bryan's answers: If your question involves a study assignment or an exam question, please add the "homework" tag.

Comment: Answers may be worth what you pay for them.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to Medical Sciences. Yes, you can ask questions about subjects that arise during your study.

However, please keep in mind that:

1. We require all questions to demonstrate [prior research](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411). You will find the rationale in the linked post. Therefore, when asking a question, please include links to sources that you have attempted to use to answer your own question.
2. Questions that ask us to refute something "my professor said" usually do not go well. We need a link to an accessible source so that we can understand the context. Ideally, these sources should be in English; I fear not many of our active users speak Arabic.
3. If possible, please frame the question in a way that it is most useful to future visitors. We want to help you, but we also want to create a repository of information for others to find later.

P.S. In the future, please ask questions related to the site *itself* on  https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/ . I have migrated this question here this time.